# Is it possible to step in source code and step out from source code with JavaScript debugger keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, javascript-debugger

I recently recognized JavaScript `debugger` keyword to put a breakpoint in JavaScript codes and debug it like this:

```
<script>

//some code....
debugger;
//some code....

</script>
```

.I have used it with Google Chrome browser and it says as in this image [image]

you can Step over with `F10`.

I want to know,Is there any shortcut key to Step in and Step out of the source code.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/shortcuts#sources-panel (the first google result for *chrome developer tools shortcuts*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after long googling I finally found this and like to share it:

```
F10 or Ctrl+' : Step over
F11 or Ctrl+; : Step into
F8 or Ctrl+/ : Continue
Shift+F11 : Step out
Ctrl+G : Go to Line
```

Comment: How in the world did you ask and answer a question at the exact same time? Asked: `2015-05-13 17:58:52Z` and answered `2015-05-13 17:58:52Z` ! Incredible! Thanks for the tip :-)

Comment: I wrote the the question text five days ago and then left to search more about the subject finally I found this answer and I like to share it both the question and the answer with you to use it because its very useful.